# .htaccess перенаправление всех доменов

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Есть сайт на WP.
На этот домен повадились цеплять другие домены.
Конечно, можно просто заблокировать другие домены, но хочется сделать красиво,  именно сделать перенаправление со всех доменов и поддоменов на основной сайт site.ru
Я пробовал различные варианты, но ни один не сработал, просьба помочь разобраться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Будет перенаправлять все домены на `www.example.com`

Comment: этот вариант не подходит, потому что тут перенаправление с 1 домена, а мне надо со всех и этих доменов я не знаю.

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы попробовали. Тут перенаправление со всех доменов, кроме `www.example.com`. Смотрите RewriteCond внимательнее. (`!`)

Comment: так там стоит условие "если домен **не** www.example.net"

Comment: да, я только хотел извиниться и написать, что вариант шикарен, а я сглупил.
Большое спасибо

Comment: @cema93, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).